# Locale not working properly

Tags: android

I have a different string for English, French and spanish. Even after setting the Locale to French, the string being displayed is still in English.
I create a string resource file under values directory named values-fr-rFR.
My code is the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
        c.setLocale(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
        getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(c);
        TextView textId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloId);
        textId.setText(R.string.hello);
    }
```

Can someone say what is wrong in my code? Here you can that I have changed the Locale to "fr". But the string being displayed in textView textId is still in English.

Comment: Did you find out the answer? I'm having the same issue with you for 3 days :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have a xml file with the localized version of the text you want to use. For instance, if you reference the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html):

English strings (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish strings (es locale), /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">¡Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can do:

```
// Get a string resource from your app's Resources
String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);

// Or supply a string resource to a method that requires a string
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

All examples and further reading can be found at the Android developer site: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have done the same. But still it doesn't work. Rather it behaves randomly. Sometimes the string gets loaded in Spanish and sometimes not. For example, if I comment out the locale and rerun, then English gets displayed. But again when I uncomment the locale line to set the locale to Spanish, the string doesn't get displayed in Spanish. But then if I modify the strings in Strings.xml present in values-es directory, then it works. What I think is that while recompiling after changing locale, the changes don't get compiled. Do you have any thoughts on it?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like it's something like that. What I gave you is the way to get the localization to work. You might have to clean/rebuild your project after loading the project or delete the project off your phone and rerun. Reference the docs that I liked out. It will work :)

Comment: I have tried clean/rebuild but it still the behavior is very random. Sometimes it works and sometimes not.